# Need to know what kind of issue is this?

Tags: mobile

It is tough to select the date of birth from the calendar. Change the calendar format so that it should be easy to choose the year. It should be user friendly,  what kind of issue is this? UI or Functional or Non Functional

Comment: As Niels mentioned this could be an UX issue or more so an usability issue.

Answer (score 2):

So what you are saying is that it is functionally working and the problem is that it unhandy to use. This would be a [UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design) issue.

> User experience design (UX, UXD, UED or XD) is the process of
>   enhancing user satisfaction with a product by improving the **usability**,
>   accessibility, and **pleasure** provided in the interaction with the
>   product.

Answer (score 0):

[Non-Functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_testing) testing includes:

- Baseline testing
- Compliance testing
- Documentation testing
- Endurance testing
- Load testing
- Localization testing and Internationalization testing
- Performance testing
- Recovery testing
- Resilience testing
- Security testing
- Scalability testing
- Stress testing
- **Usability testing**
- Volume testing